# ¿Se pueden traducir preguntas escritas en ingles sin ser el OP?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, ediciones-sugeridas, colas-de-revisión

En la cola de revisión de **ediciones sugeridas** he visto varias sugerencias de ediciones a preguntas que inicialmente habían sido redactadas en inglés y un usuario diferente al OP la traduce a español (en todas las incidencias que pude ver era el mismo usuario el que las editaba), incluso habían unas sugerencias que ya tenían un primer voto como aceptada, pero aun así yo las rechacé.

La semana pasada se hablaba en el chat de SOes sobre un caso similar, donde se dijo que una persona diferente al OP no debería de traducir la pregunta ya que no sabemos si el OP habla español.

Entonces quisiera saber exactamente que hacer al ver estos casos (usuarios diferentes al OP traduciendo la pregunta y usuarios aprobando dichas sugerencias).

Comment: Hiciste bien en rechazarlas. Y si resulta que se aprueban, está bien hacer una reversión. Yo muchas veces agrego como motivo de rechazo el enlace a la pregunta que es duplicada de esta:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No se deberian aprobar.

Las traducciones tienen que ser hechas por el usuario original, si no ademas de que no estariamos enseñando al usuario que aca hay que preguntar en español, puede ser que OP ni siquiera sepa español (algo raro, por que por algun motivo pregunto aca, pero puede pasar).

De igual forma, tampoco se deben traducir respuestas (si estan en ingles) y tampoco se deben contestar preguntas formuladas en ingles, por mas que se contesten en español.

El sitio es en español, para ingles hay un sitio en ingles. Permitir esas ediciones facilita las cosas para OP, pero no enseña el correcto uso del sitio. En preguntas simples puede ser mas facil hacer eso que esperar que OP las traduzca por si mismo. Pero para algo tenemos algunas reglas, y no respetarlas implica el cierre de la pregunta.

De ser necesario, y si vale la pena, cualquier puede formular la pregunta nuevamente en español y contestarla libremente.

En muchos casos de preguntas en ingles que no fueron traducidas, estas fueron directamente abandonadas.

Answer (score 2):

Es mejor rechazarlas.

Si el autor original no sabe castellano el traducirla no le va a ayudar.

Si el autor original sí sabe castellano es mejor que haga el mismo la traducción. Lo ideal es que los usuarios aprendan a usar el sitio sin depender de que un tercero venga a arreglar sus preguntas o respuestas.

Aunque esto podría crear una situación inconveniente. ¿Qué ocurre si la pregunta a ti realmente te interesa? Si la haces tu en castellano te puedes encontrar con el autor original traduciendola después y entonces habría un duplicado. Esperar a que se cierre o a que el autor original la traduzca introduce una espera que no es deseable. Un usuario que hace un uso correcto del sitio no tiene por que encontrarse con un retraso a la hora de preguntar porque otro usuario haga un uso incorrecto. En este caso particular sí vería bien traducir tu mismo la pregunta y **añadir** un comentario explicando por qué la ha traducido. Siguiendo este mismo criterio, si se hizo la traducción pero no hay ninguna indicación respecto a que el traductor está interesado en la respuesta a la pregunta entonces sin duda rechazaría la edición.